# Platform emulators for Java AWT Swing Testing

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, windows, swing

I have noticed slight variations in how Java AWT/Swing application behave on a Windows vs. Linux.

Given the following development environment:
-Windows 7
-Eclipse Kepler
-JDK 1.7

Is there any way to preview a Java AWT/Swing application as it would display in Linux?

I realize that I can deploy to a Linux workstation or VM, but was curious if there is another way. Such as an emulator plugin for eclipse.

Comment: Consider using a virtual machine, like [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/), but remember, this is only virtual environment, nothing bets running it on actual hardware/software

Comment: *"Such as an emulator plugin for eclipse"* which would be a ... virtual machine...?

Comment: *"..how Java AWT/Swing application behave"*  Behave in what way?  Are we talking graphics rendering, fonts and activation keys, component sizing or look..?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have a dialog whose components fit nicely when run on windows and are slightly out of the dialog's viewable area when run on linux.  I also have a frame which reliably maximizes on windows but only occasionally for linux.

Comment: Does the app. use layout managers, and always `pack()` the top level container (dialog, frame..)?

Comment: I took some time and got to the bottom of these issues (Maximize issue was pack which happened too early, and the dialog issue was resolved by changing a BoxLayout rigidArea to horizontalGlue).